# Pandas get numbers in column to increase based on previous rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

So I have some data that groups rows based on a number in the column 'Code'. This data is somewhat corrupted however and sometimes does not take the previous row's max as new number but resets it to 1.

Basically the data looks like this:

```
   Code      Date
0      1  20200501
1      1  20200502
2      2  20200502
3      2  20200502
4      3  20200502
5      3  20200505
6      1  20200505
7      1  20200505
8      2  20200505
9      2  20200505
10     1  20200505
11     1  20200505
12     6  20200505
13     6  20200505
```

the numbering in the code column is corrupted here and should look like this

```
   Code      Date
0      1  20200501
1      1  20200502
2      2  20200502
3      2  20200502
4      3  20200502
5      3  20200505
6      4  20200505
7      4  20200505
8      5  20200505
9      5  20200505
10     4  20200505
11     4  20200505
12     6  20200505
13     6  20200505
```

Can someone help me find a way to fix this data numbering?

EDIT:
edited this to provide some more info

So the data groups rows based on numbers. so everything with the same number is part of a group. The numbering in the code column should go up, starting at 1. sometimes however the numbering resets back to 1. so i might have 1-2-3-1, which should be 1-2-3-4, if that makes sense.

Comment: Could you explain the logic a bit more? Thank you

Comment: yes I will try to explain it better

Comment: Are you wanting to add the values of previous rows when the value of `Code` decreases?

Comment: @Alex yes exactly, when the value resets to 1, 1 should be replace with the previous rows highest number, + 1

Comment: Why does the code for 20200505 start at 3?

Comment: @norie because it its part of a new group, I did not include the groups in the df because I did not feel like it was necesarry since I just need to update the code numbering when it has reset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on what I understand, you can try this which uses cummax to determine if the existing value is lesser than the previous max and based on it adds the existing value to it:

```
a = df['Code'].cummax()
s = a>df['Code']
df['New_Code'] = np.where(s,a+df['Code'],df['Code']
```

---

```
print(df)

    Code      Date  New_Code
0      1  20200501         1
1      1  20200502         1
2      2  20200502         2
3      2  20200502         2
4      3  20200502         3
5      3  20200505         3
6      1  20200505         4
7      1  20200505         4
8      2  20200505         5
9      2  20200505         5
10     1  20200505         4
11     1  20200505         4
12     6  20200505         6
13     6  20200505         6
```

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I ment, thanks a lot!

Comment: If you add three extra rows using: `df = df.append(pd.DataFrame({"Code": [1, 2, 1], "Date": [1, 2, 3]}))`  this doesn't work. i.e it only works when the max number is the last or penultimate sequence

Comment: @Alex what doesn't work if I may ask? I tested and it worked for me

Comment: @Anky, I'm not sure now. Does it need to always be increasing, @Tea-F-Tea? I was working on the assumption that rows 9-12 would go `5, 6, 6, 7, 7`, which maybe incorrect?

Comment: @Alex ahh I see your point :) I think OP meant is when cumulative maximum breaks (not incremental but cumulative) , add the row to the previous maximum value. Thats what i have in mine (: which matched the expected output too,

Comment: Indeed @anky that is exactly what I ment, when cum breaks not incremental. Thank you for explaining it that way